# VB: Changing shortcut properites

Tags: file, vb6, shortcut

I have a code, which task would be changing .url or .lnk (shortcuts) properties, but it does not seem to do anything.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Shell32

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        'References Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation.
        'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776890%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
    End Sub
    Public Sub Change_Shortcut()

    Dim shell As Shell32.Shell
    Dim folder As Shell32.Folder
    Dim folderItem As Shell32.FolderItem
    Dim shortcut As Shell32.ShellLinkObject

    shell = New Shell32.Shell

    folder = shell.NameSpace("C:\Users\GrzegoP\Desktop\xxx") 'Shortcut path
    If Not folder Is Nothing Then
        folderItem = folder.ParseName("o2.url") 'Shortcut name
        If Not folderItem Is Nothing Then
            shortcut = folderItem.GetLink
            If Not shortcut Is Nothing Then
                shortcut.Path = "www.o2.ie" 'new shortcut address
                shortcut.Save()
                MsgBox("Shortcut changed")
            Else
                MsgBox("Shortcut link within file not found")
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Shortcut file not found")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Desktop folder not found")
    End If

End Sub

End Module
```

Can anyone give me some advice where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What message box ends up showing up?  Would be good to know what error you're getting, if any.

Comment: it is not showing any message just running interrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's noted here that you cannot create a URL shortcut that way:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You should instead simply create a `xxx.url` file on the desktop, writing the following lines of text inside of it:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.o2.ie
```

Windows will turn that into a web-site shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, it sounds like nothing is getting executed.  Try putting a breakpoint at the beginning of the sub to see if it even gets called.  If it does not, then make sure you're able to properly connect the `Change_Shortcut()` so it gets called appropriately.

Once you set up your breakpoint, you should be able to walk through the code and see where you end up to ensure it all works as expected.

Comment: ok did it and I get an Exception from HRESULT: 0x80041001 on this line of code: shortcut.Path = "www.o2.ie"

Comment: Added a new answer.  If my solution helped you discover the issue, please accept my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to my problem...

in the line: `shortcut.Path = "www.o2.ie"`

I forgot to put `http://` in front of the address.